# Parralelise a simple computation

Tags: python, parallel-processing

Suppose i have a simple class and some objects from it :

```
class Myclass:

    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a

    def square(self):
        self.a = self.a**2

list_of_objects = [Myclass(x) for x in range(10)]
```

How can i compute :

```
for obj in list_of_objects:
    obj.square()
```

in a parallel way ?

Of course my class is way more complicated, but syntax should be the same..

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into Python's multiprocessing module. You could do something like:

```
import multiprocessing

procs = []
for obj in list_of_objects:
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target = obj.square)
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

Although, with this simple example, it is slower to use multiprocessing because of the overhead involved in setting up the processes. In this case when I timed it, it was faster to just do it serialized. So, I would try actually timing your more complicated code to make sure it is worth the overhead.

Comment: Exactly the entry i needed into the documentation; Thanks a lot